# Error en blanco cuando ejecuto mi aplicación. Java

Tags: java, eclipse

Cuando ejecuto este código.

Se me muestra una ventana de error completamente en blanco, sin ningún tipo de **error**.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Heron {

public static void main(String[]Args) {

    // (a+b+c)/2 || ((a+b+c)/2)-a
    int a,b,c,Perimetro;
    float Total;

    Scanner Datos=new Scanner (System.in); 

    System.out.println("Escribe el valor de a: ");
    a=Datos.nextInt();

    System.out.println("Escribe el valor de b: ");
    b=Datos.nextInt();

    System.out.println("Escribe el valor de c: ");
    c=Datos.nextInt();

    Perimetro = ((a+b+c)/2);

    Total = (Perimetro * (Perimetro - a) * (Perimetro - b) * (Perimetro - c));

    System.out.println(Math.sqrt(Total));


}

}
```

¿Sabéis porque puede ser?
Muchas gracias!
Un saludo.

Comment: Bienvenido al sitio RubenMG, en este caso en realidad no tienes ningún error,, reinicia tu eclipse y trata nuevamente.

Comment: @RubenMG tu codigo no da ningun error asi como dice Jorgesys

Answer (score 0):

El error puede surgir en tu variable total ya que la defines como float y todas las demas en int, te sugiero que la cambies a float todas ya que tu operación necesita números decimales.

Comment: El código en realidad no tiene error. Revisar [answer]. Se esta realizando un casting implicito.

Answer (score -1):

Declara `datos` (en la declaracion del `Scanner`) en minusculas, no como `Datos`. Es posible que te lo esté detectando como una clase la cual no existe o no estas importando.

Comment: El código en realidad no tiene error. Revisar [answer]